# HTTP Error 403.14 in ASP.NET MVC2 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

This is my error... And I do NOT have IIS 7.0 installed locally. This is a remote host, which I pay for.

I found out how to fix this, but requires me to enter the IIS manager, which i can't.

Is there any way in Web.config I can tell the browser it should load up the default view or at least use the Routing table with the default route?

EDIT: Am I misunderstanding how to deploy an MVC2 project? It's not just copy the files or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version IIS are they running? What is your worker process setup to run? If its in classic mode, then you need a mapping from .mvc (or wildcard *.*) to aspnet_isapi. If its in integrated pipeline mode things should be a bit better. How did you deploy your MVC binaries? Put a test.aspx page in your app in the root folder - can you get to that?

So - 
1. make sure your site  works with an aspx file in it at the root
2. see what version iis your hoster is on and if they have setup anything for MVC if on iis6. If its IIS 7 ensure you are in integrated pipeline mode and not classic.

Comment: Setting the Pipeline mode to Integrated instead of Classic did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

When I see this error on new servers at work it's usually because iis wasn't installed before .net was. You have to run the aspnet_regiis.exe -r on the server to register .net with iis...

I know this isn't what you want to hear but you should probably contact support of the hosting company and see if they can verify or not.